# Gurobi - Solving Capacity Location Problem

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, gurobi

I am trying to solve a Capacity location Problem from the OR database named: capa

OR files [here](http://people.brunel.ac.uk/%7Emastjjb/jeb/orlib/capinfo.html)

The answer should be:

`capa 19240822.449 (capacity 8000)`

But I found:

`Best objective 3.145815023928e+08`

For sure it is a problem on my code... Can someone help me?
Maybe I am doing something wrong on the Optmization formula ... or on the construction of my shipping demand. I really do not know, because it looks correct to me.

Any help would be appreciated... thanks in advance

```
from itertools import product
from math import sqrt
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB
import time

# Get Clients and Facilities
def getFacilities_Clients(file_list):
    return int(file_list[0]), int(file_list[1])

# Get Facilities Fixed Costs
def getFacilities_STRCapacity_FixedCosts(file_list, num_facilities):
    shift = 2
    capacity = []
    cost = []
    
    #loop to get all i location costs
    for i in range(0,num_facilities*2,2):
        #capacity.append(file_list[i+shift])
        capacity.append(8000)
        cost.append(int(file_list[i+1+shift].replace(".","")))
    
    return capacity, cost

# Get Demand and Allocation Costs for j(customer) to each i(client)
def getClient_Demand_AllocationCosts(file_list, num_facilities, num_customers):
    shift = 2 + (num_facilities*2)
    demand = []
    allocation_cost = []
    
    #loop to get all j Clients 
    j=0
    for r in range(0,num_customers):
    
        #get demand
        demand.append(int(file_list[j+shift]))

        #loop to get all i location costs
        for i in range(0,num_facilities):
            allocation_cost.append(float(file_list[j+1+i+shift]))
            
        #fix j
        j += num_facilities+1
 
    
    return demand, allocation_cost

#Read File from OR datasets
fileName='datasets/ORcapa'
ORlist = []

with open(fileName, "r") as f:
    ORlist = f.read().split()

##### Sets and Indices #####
num_facilities, num_customers = getFacilities_Clients(ORlist)
capacity, fixed_cost = getFacilities_STRCapacity_FixedCosts(ORlist, num_facilities)
cartesian_prod = list(product(range(num_customers), range(num_facilities)))
# shipping costs
demand, alloc_cost = getClient_Demand_AllocationCosts(ORlist, num_facilities, num_customers)
shipping_cost = dict(zip(cartesian_prod, alloc_cost))

shipping_demand={}
for k, v in shipping_cost.items():
    shipping_demand[k] = v * demand[k[0]]

#setup cost
setup_cost = fixed_cost
#demand of customer
dc = demand
#max production
maxp= capacity

start = time.time()
# MIP  model formulation
m = gp.Model('CFLP')

##### Decision Variable #####
x = m.addVars(num_facilities, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name='x')
y = m.addVars(cartesian_prod, ub=1, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name='y')

##### Constraints #####
m.addConstrs((y[(c,f)] <= x[f] for c,f in cartesian_prod), name='Shipping')
m.addConstrs((gp.quicksum(y[(c,f)] for f in range(num_facilities)) == 1 for c in range(num_customers)), name='Demand')
m.addConstrs((gp.quicksum(dc[c]*y[(c,f)] for c in range(num_customers)) <= maxp[f]*x[f] for f in range(num_facilities)), name='Capacity')

##### Objective Function #####
m.setObjective(x.prod(setup_cost)+y.prod(shipping_demand), GRB.MINIMIZE)

m.Params.Method = 1
# Options are:-1=automatic, 0=primal simplex, 1=dual simplex, 2=barrier, 3=concurrent, 4=deterministic concurrent, 5=deterministic concurrent simplex

m.optimize()
end = time.time()
```

Comment: A useful debugging tool is to write out and inspect the LP file.

Answer (score 0):

that solved my issue:

m.setObjective(x.prod(setup_cost)+y.prod(shipping_cost), GRB.MINIMIZE)

I was computing a different value for the shipping.